# C in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, sublimetext3

I have Windows 8.1.

I want to compile and run .c file in Sublime Text 3 just as C IDE or CodeBlockes. I tried a lot of things described on some other posts of StackOverflow and watched some videos too but nothing worked for me so posting this question. :) Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: `described on this Forum`..there you go wrong..

Comment: Show us what you've been trying? You made a build system?

Comment: AFAIK ST is hardly an IDE, its pretty good editor, but not an IDE. You may be able to setup some kind of macro or something under hotkey which would trigger compilation and/or running, but you will have to have external compiler to do that i guess...

Comment: {
        "windows":
        {
            "cmd": ["cc","-std=c99" ,"$file_name","-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lm", "-Wall", "&","Start" , "${file_base_name}.exe"]
        },
        "selector" : "source.c",
        "shell": true,
        "working_dir" : "$file_path",
    }
This is the build system I found somewhere.. It is working but I'm getting the output screen only for 1 sec and then it gets closed. :(

Comment: stupid question but did u add `system('pause');` or `getchar();` at the end of your program ? (assuming it is something simple ofc) - cause otherwise your program would run, but as soon as it finished there would be no need for command line window and it would close

Comment: @4rlekin, OMG It worked for me I typed system("pause") at the end of my code and it worked. Really love you. <3

Comment: hahaha glad i could help, and if that makes you so happy wait till you start to encounter some really awful problems - StackOverflow FTW! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your system don't have MinGW compiler!! If that's the case, download it by visiting their site. If you have already done that, the only thing I can think of is that you have not edited the path variable value in your system properties.

For this, follow these simple steps :

1. Go to "My Computer" or "This PC" or whatever name you have given to it.
2. Right click and select "Properties".
3. Click on "Advanced system settings" present on left hand side.
4. Click on "Environment Variables" present at the bottom under "Advanced" tab in the "System      Properties"
5. Select the "Path" variable in the "System variables" and select the "Edit" option.
6. At the end of the contents written in "Variable Value", add this

   ;C:\MinGW\bin

and your .c files should compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

I typed `system("pause")` at the end of my code and it worked. –  Aedy